# Unable to get the selected pick list value in the controller

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, community

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" extensions="MyOrderPadController" >   
     <apex:detail />
        <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!reset}" value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>   
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Order Pad">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Order_Description__c}"  />        
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Creat_Date__c}"  />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Closed_Date__c}"  />
                     <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Conformation__c}"  />  
                      <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.User_Description__c}" />
                       <apex:selectList id="bidpro"  size="1" >
                   <b>  Bid Pro &nbsp; </b><apex:selectOptions value="{!bidpro}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>                   
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:MyOrderPadController**

```
public class MyOrderPadController {
    public Order__c order{ get; private set; }
     List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); 
     public List<selectOption> getbidpro() 
     {

      options.add(new selectOption('', '- None -')); 
      options.add(new selectOption('a', 'A')); 
      options.add(new selectOption('b', 'B')); 
      options.add(new selectOption('c', 'C')); 
      return options; 

      }



    NewAndExistingController  test = new NewAndExistingController ();

        public MyOrderPadController ()
       {

       }
    public MyOrderPadController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {

        order = (Order__c)sc.getRecord();
        order.Order_Description__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bidpro')+':'+options;
        order.Account__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('aid');  
    }
public PageReference edit() 
     { 
           return null;        
     }
     public PageReference reset()
     {
          PageReference newpage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());

          newpage.setRedirect(true);
          return newpage;
    }
     public PageReference save() 
     {
          TRY
          {              
               order.Name = 'Demo Test Order '+order.Order_Description__c;
               order.Order_Description__c =''';**//set the selected pick list option here**                              IF(order.Conformation__c == TRUE){


                    INSERT order; 
                    PageReference newpage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());
                    newpage.setRedirect(true);
                    return newpage;     
                    }


                    }   

          catch(System.DMLException e) 
          {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            SYSTEM.DEBUG('ERROR ORDER PAD CONTROLLER :'+e);
            return null;
          }

        return null;        
     }   
}
```

I am unable to get the selected pick list value in the controller.The VF page contains custom object fields and one dynamic pick list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the code in page

```
<apex:selectList value="{!bidpro}" size="1" rendered="true">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectedOptionValue}">         
          </apex:selectOptions>     
      </apex:selectList>
```

and get set the value in controller like

```
public string selectedOptionValue{get;set;}
```

and use it up wherever u want in controller.

Comment: see the bellow link also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21847/select-option-out-put/21849#21849

Comment: I ran into an issue with this code. It complains that selectList value should be read only, so I cannot modify it in getBidPro method. How can I get around this to populate values for the selectList? Thanks.