# How to take selected value from picklist?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following code..but i am not able to use the selected value to set the value for case object . Please help.

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Select A Queue">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select A Queue">

           <apex:selectList size="1">
               Select Queue :   <apex:selectOptions value="{!QueueList}"></apex:selectOptions>

           </apex:selectList> 
         <br/><br/>

           <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="save" />
           <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="cancel"/>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>  

</apex:form>
```

```
   public class QueueController {
   public List<Group> GroupNameList  = new List<Group>();

private final Case caseObj;

public QueueController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
              this.caseObj = (Case)controller.getRecord();
        }

public List<SelectOption> QueueList 
{
    get
    {
        GroupNameList  = [select g.Id, g.Name from Group g where Type = 'Queue'];

        QueueList = new List<SelectOption>();

        for(Group temp : GroupNameList)
        {
            QueueList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Name));
        }
        return QueueList;
    }
    set;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Can you please check the link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/unable-to-get-the-selected-pick-list-value-in-the-controller I hope It helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try the below code :

For controller:

```
public class QueueController {
   public List<Group> GroupNameList{get;set;}

    private final Case caseObj{get;set;}

    public String queue {get;set;}

    public QueueController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
              this.caseObj = (Case)controller.getRecord();
            GroupNameList = new List<Group>();
        }


    public List<SelectOption> QueueList 
    {
        get
        {
            GroupNameList  = [select g.Id, g.Name from Group g where Type = 'Queue'];

            QueueList = new List<SelectOption>();

            for(Group temp : GroupNameList)
            {
                QueueList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Name));
            }
            return QueueList;
        }
        set;
        }

}

public PageReference saveCase(){
    caseobj.ownerid = queue;
    upsert caseobj;
    PageReference ref = new PageReference('/'+caseobj.id);
    return ref;
}
```

For VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Select A Queue">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select A Queue">
            Select Queue :
           <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!queue}">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!QueueList}"></apex:selectOptions>

           </apex:selectList> 
         <br/><br/>

           <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveCase}" id="save" />
           <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="cancel"/>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: public QueueController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
              this.caseObj = (Case)controller.getRecord();
            GroupNameList = new List<Group>();
            this.caseObj.ownerid = queue.getValue;
        }    will this be used to extract the value out of it?

Comment: Instead of queue.getValue use "this.caseObj.ownerid = queue"

Comment: After adding that line of code ... on click of save I am not able to navigate back on the case page... can u pls tel why is it so... how can we send the data pack to update the field on case page

Comment: are you doing the above code in controller?

Comment: I have added this for overriding but it is still not working for me  public PageReference save() 
     {
          TRY
          {       this.caseObj.ownerid = queue;
                update this.caseObj;
                 PageReference newpage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());
                    newpage.setRedirect(true);
                    return newpage;    

           }   
      catch(System.DMLException e) 
      {
          ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            SYSTEM.DEBUG('ERROR  :'+e);
            return null;
          }
  return null;        
 }

Comment: I have updated the code plz refer to it.

Comment: I am still not able to send the selected value back to the case page...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a property in the class to store a string

In the `<apex:selectlist>`you put that property in the `value=` tag