# Value of the picklist does not come to the Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:selectList label="ID:" rendered="{!!IsNewAccount}" 
    id="id" value="{!MYTextField__c}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!orgIds}"/>
</apex:selectList>

public List<SelectOption> getOrgIds() {
    return options
}
```

Above control method does return some values and i can see them in the VF page picklist.

But once i submitted `MYTextField__c` is always null. I need `MYTextField__c` value to be the value selected from Picklist.

Comment: I went through this question also, but i'm getting an error saying selectList shouldbe readOnly
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/unable-to-get-the-selected-pick-list-value-in-the-controller

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it :

**VF Page**

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedTag}" multiselect="true" size="5">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!tagName}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

**Apex Class - Page Controller**

```
/*class variables*/
public static String[] selectedTag{get;set;}

//I get my options from a custom setting
public List<selectOption> tagName{
    get {
        List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();

        Map<String, Tags__c> tagsss = Tags__c.getAll();
        List<String> listTags = new List<String>();
        listTags.addAll(tagsss.keySet());

        for (String name : listTags) {
            tags__c tag = tagsss.get(name);
            options.add(new SelectOption(tag.Name, tag.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }
    set;
}

//Constructor
public ClassName() {
    selectedTag = new String[]{};
}

//Class method
public String search(){
  System.debug('## selectedTag : ' + selectedTag);

  //do any processing that you want with the value 
}
```

It should work this way.
You should get your selected value in the variable 'selectedTag'.